# php converting exponetial value having exponent > 12 to decimal

Tags: php, floating-point, type-conversion, exponential

I am reading a value from excel file when it is a number >= 14 digit it convert this to something like 3.5775004173581E+14 I want to get the exact value in decimal like 3.57750041735819 I have tried

```
(float) 3.5775004173581e+14                         O/P 3.5775004173581e+14     
intval((float) 3.5775004173581e+14)                 O/P 740815490
number_format(3.5775004173581e+14)                  O/P 3.57750041735810
```

but former return the same string as O/P second one produces some garbage value where as works well for the exponent <14 and the number_format adds traling 0 after 14 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because float [`precision`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) setting is default `14`. To change this, use [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/ini_set), for example.Then you'll be able to get proper values. Sample:

```
$strVal = "1234567890.123456789";
//float(1234567890.1235), because 
//default precision is 14:
var_dump((double)$strVal);

//float(1234567890.123456717)
ini_set('precision', 19);
var_dump((double)$strVal);
```

This is not only about **decimal** precision, but about **float** precision
:

```
$strVal = "1234567890123456789";
var_dump((double)$strVal);//float(1.2345678901235E+18)

ini_set('precision', 19);
var_dump((double)$strVal);//float(1234567890123456768)
```

Also, important note - it seems that trying to overcome precision in your case is an attempt to resolve symptoms, not the problem. So you should choose correct data model rather than try to solve this "problem".

Comment: Rolled back (to version with note) - because my opinion is - solving this problem is a case of [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).